# What is the relationship between the characters 'r' and '≲'?

Tags: utf-8

I'm having some sort of Unicode issue.

I'm getting the value "retscache" displayed as "≲整獣慣桥⼱昶户㜳" instead.

I checked the Debugging Table at http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html and did not find these characters.

What is the relationship between the characters 'r' and '≲'?

I'm hoping with this piece of info, I can figure out what's wrong, e.g. double-encoding, reverse encoding, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Python, it looks like `retscache` is being interpreted as big-endian UTF-16:

```
>>> s='≲整獣慣桥⼱昶户㜳'
>>> s.encode('utf-16be')
b'"retscache/1f6b773'
```

Comment: Root cause... Java code was incorrectly calling ByteBuffer.asChars() instead of ByteBuffer.array() .. as a result combining each pair of 2 bytes as one char.

Comment: Explicitly: `'≲'` in UTF-16BE is 0x22 0x72. 0x22 0x72 in UTF-8 (and many other encodings) is `'"'` `'r'`. Presumably what stuffed the buffer was UTF-8 (or compatible for the sample data).